# Dont want soft keyboard to automatically show on launch - Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Every time I open my android app, it automatically focuses the `EditText` box and the soft keyboard opens up. Is there a way to focus something else on start up so the keyboard doesn't show right away?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

for your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 6):

Add this two lines to you main layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

Add in your layout definition (in xml file) this following options :

```
android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```