# SoftKeyboard on EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Introduzca codigo de comercial"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textocontrasena"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="5" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginlogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textocontrasena"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/xmlbotonzarko"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

My problem is that the softkeyboard is opening automatically when I enter on the Activity.
What I want is the softkeyboard to open just when the user clicks on the EditText(not before).

Thanks!

Comment: on which device you are testing?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11542820/1289716

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this inside the manifest for your activity: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `Activity` code in your `Android Manifest` that is associated with this layout by adding either:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

or,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

so that it would look something like:

```
<activity
    android:name="my.package.name.MyActivity"
    android:label="MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  <!-- Pick one of -->
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />        <!-- these two   -->
```

This should prevent the softkeyboard from automatically opening up on activity start.

Answer (score 0):

put the focus on another view, and try to add this for your TextEdit View `android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Example change focus : ((yourView)findViewById(R.id.your_id)).requestFocus();